# jquery table rows margin

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way in jquery to set top-margin of 1st row of table from its header,

like,

```
------------------
Header of table
------------------

--some margin--

------------------
Here comes the 1st row
------------------
```

I tried,

```
$('#table-id .row-class').css('margin-top', 20);
```

it does'nt work, while if i use this,

```
$('#table-id').css('margin-top', 20);
```

it shift the whole table down,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#table-id tr:eq(1) td").css('padding','25px');
```

**[Fiddle DEMO >>](http://jsfiddle.net/3qJAK/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#table-id .row-class').css('padding-top', '20px');
```

Comment: really sorry, i forgot to add 'px' inmy question, that does'nt work

Comment: use padding-top please @faanahmed

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the margin of a table cell. But you CAN change the padding. Change the padding of the TD:

```
$('#table-id .row-class').css('padding-top', 20+'px');
```

Comment: there is no need of `20+'px'`, merely `'20px'` will do the job